# HSTSpreload, www subdomain and redirect issues

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I looking for add my website to hstspreload list and the issue is it detect my website with www as a subdomain. I check web like amazon including www and it dont is detected how a subdomain (it is already preload in his list). Possible solutions:

1) Make changes in my VPS nginx.conf to be detected my website including www how Not subdomain in hstspreload_org (This is the desired solution)

2) Add my website to preload list without www and for it I should make many redirects: First from http:// to https://mywebsite and Second from previous path to https://www.mywebsite

How could I add my web to hstspreload list with www and avoiding multiple redirects?

If is not possible avoid two redirects, then say me please what code should to add for these redirects because I tried various htaccess rewrite conditions unsucessfully

Best regards